# FORTRAN, what do you recommend for a development environment

Tags: fortran

I need to start developing in FORTRAN, any recommendations on learning\developing FORTRAN coming from the .NET area?  Any recommended environments that are close to Visual Studio?  Visual Fortran looked really promising, but is a bit pricey, and look like it wouldn't compile with gcc.

Comment: This question is probably [off-topic on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), though it might be a good question for [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: well, it is ten years old ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eclipse is a great IDE for Java and apparently there is support for Fortran... see:

http://www.eclipse.org/photran/

Comment: how did you find using the eclipse plugin?

Comment: IMHO, Photran really isn't so great. It has been a great pain to setup and I've gotten only limited success interfacing the GDB GUI it provides.

Answer (score 2):

What about Visual Studio + Intel Fortran ?  I use that combination when I port a program to Windows.  Don't know nuthin about .NET though.

There isn't much of a buzz around the Fortran world about Eclipse+Photran.  An awful lot of us Fortran hackers think that Emacs is an IDE.

Finally, on Linux you might try Sun Studio Express -- it's free and includes Fortran, C, C++ compilers and an IDE based on NetBeans (actually, I think it is NetBeans)